# How do I display a VisualForce page on the Reports tab?

Tags: reporting, datatable

I have built a custom report using SOQL and displayed it using the DataTables JQuery plugin.  Now I need to add a link to it on the Reports tab so that users see it alongside the rest of their reports.  I don't want to create a custom tab, if possible, since I only want to "inject" this VF page as a report on the standard Reports tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative you could consider is to create a home page component entitled 'Key reports' that you show on the sidebar. The component would contain a set of home page custom links ..

- some of which point at regular SFDC reports
- and one that would point at your VF page
- and perhaps one that simply reads as 'More ...' that links to the Reports tab

This way, users look on the sidebar first for the hot reports, including your cool JQuery report

Comment: I like this idea - thx!

Comment: A bit better for me: I created a VF page with links to my custom reports and one link to the standard Reports tab.  Then I added a VF tab linked to the VF page listing the reports.  Just a slight redirection from the main reports, which is fine since users really want to see their pre-defined reports more than the full-blown report tab.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. You can't add visualforce pages to the reports tab and therefore you need to provide s separate tab or a link elsewhere.